# What does *(void **) (&funcp) do in this line of code involving dlsym()?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

Could somebody help me interpret this line of code (from [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/shlibs/dynload.c.html))?

```
*(void **) (&funcp) = dlsym(libHandle, argv[2]);
```

I do not understand what `*(void **) (&funcp)` does.

Comment: Where did you find this line?

Comment: Using the dlopen API
 in shared library

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You said please interpret it, you didn't say which part you were confused by. Therefore to let people waste time answering your question more fully without showing a little gratitude to them is a disservice to the community IMO.

Comment: I think it's an alright question. The reasons why they're doing that as opposed to just `funcp = ...` are pretty subtle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might clarify it (from [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/shlibs/dynload.c.html)):

(**Update**: *I didn't include the exact same link to be snarky. I missed the link in the original question.* :P)

```
/* The rather clumsy cast above is necessary because the ISO C standard
   does not require that pointers to functions can be cast back and
   forth to 'void *'. (See TLPI pages 863-864.) SUSv3 TC1 and SUSv4
   accept the ISO C requirement and propose casts of the above
   form as the workaround. However, the 2013 Technical Corrigendum
   (TC1) to SUSv4 requires casts of the following more natural form
   to work correctly:

       funcp = (void (*)()) dlsym(libHandle, argv[2]);

   Various current compilers (e.g., gcc with the '-pedantic' flag)
   may still complain about such casts, however. */
```

It's basically a hack to avoid having to cast the `void*` from `dlsym()` to a function pointer, by instead reinterpreting the data in `funcp` as a `void*` and storing into that. This is done by taking the address of `funcp` (the address of the variable itself), pretending that the address refers to a `void*` (via the `(void**)` cast), dereferencing it, and storing the `void*` from `dlsym()` into it. Simpler forms are likely to work in practice too.

This method of "reinterpreting" data by taking its address, casting that address to a pointer to a different type, and dereferencing, is often called *type punning* by the way. The *pun* comes from the same data having different meanings when interpreted in different ways, which is how real puns work too.

(Type punning can be unsafe in certain circumstances, including when the compiler makes use of *strict aliasing rules*, which lets it assume that certain pointers of different type do not *alias* (that they do not refer to the same data). The cast above might violate strict aliasing as you get a function pointer and a `void*` referring to the same data, though it's a "likely to work in practice" thing in this case.)

(The reason ISO C does not require that function pointers can be safely cast to `void` pointers and back is probably that functions and data (`void` pointers refer to "data") are stored separately on some machines. Since they are separate, they might also use different address lengths or formats, so that casting between function pointers and data pointers might not make sense. Architectures that separate code and data in that way are called *Harvard architectures*.)

Comment: I think it'd be worth mentioning that this ugly hack is breaking strict aliasing rules and the preferable way is casting to a function pointer (like in your quote).

Comment: @cremno: Hmm, yeah, maybe I could squeeze strict aliasing rules in there too. Wondering if decent coverage would make the answer too rambling though. :)

Comment: @cremno: Made an attempt!

Answer (score 0):

dlsym() relates to dlopen() and dlclose() See the man pages.

The line you're seeing it is looking up a symbol (fetching the value of the symbol, and in this case is presuming it is a function address), in the binary object loaded at dlopen(), and assigning it to the pointer variable **funcp**.

When **funcp** is typecast to the corresponding function type, meaning given the proper function signature, that function can be called via funcp and parameters passed as well.

dl (dynamic library) set of functions are the mechanism by which plugins are typically facilitated on systems that support dlopen/dlsym/dlclose. The plugin has to conform to  an interface defined by the user, or community, that the code that wants to load the plugin must also know, so that knows how to find and define the symbols by name, and how to cast them and use them.

Another way of putting it, is it lets you make calls into an object that isn't available at link time and lets your code do at runtime what the linker handles for you at link time.

dlsym() returns a (void *) because it can't assume anything about the symbol it's loading, which could be a variable, a function entry point, etc... to do anything with the value returned, you generally need to cast it into the type that corresponds to the symbol in the binary loaded with dlopen().

Comment: Great. And you knew the other stuff too? Because I have no idea what you know and don't know or whether your question pertains more to dlsym() itself or to the way the value returned has been cast into a void *, etc... so I try to cover all the bases

Comment: Also, later, someone who doesn't know about dlopen() may stumble on this question and then they can get more context.  If you like the question and respect the effort people put into helping you, and find anything useful to you, please vote it up and return the favor